# Creating and Deleting Pictures/Screenshots

Tags: c#, screenshot

Well, happens that im writing a program to take some screenshots and having some difficulty dealing with files being already in use by another process, hopefully someone can help me find a way to "close" this process or enlight me how to proceed.

```
//Create a new bitmap.
var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

// Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

// Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                            0,
                            0,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

// Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
//bmpScreenshot.Save(nomeScreen + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmpScreenshot.Save(@"c:\temp\"+nomeScreen+".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
count++;
nomeScreen = "S"+Convert.ToString(count);
```

This is what I have (i know, poor programing skills) to take several screenshots, however later on I want them to be deleted from the place where I'm storing them

http://gyazo.com/4b50945b0d157d082f7897e34a705560

This is a screenshot of what it occurs. How do I "close" the bitmap? The only actions that the program does so far is taking screenshots and delete them.

```
string pathString = "C:\\temp";
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(pathString);
foreach (var k in d.GetFiles("*.jpeg"))
{
    File.Delete(pathString+"\\" + k);
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to close the bitmap, I'd imagine the error could arise there but it is unclear where you do actually get the error

Comment: @Sayse http://gyazo.com/4b50945b0d157d082f7897e34a705560 The program only takes screenshots and saves them into that folder. After taknig these screenshots, I want to delete them  and that is when the error arises,I have tried the Dispose method, how do I close the bitmap?

Comment: I meant dispose, but you are probably better off using a `using` block.

Comment: @Sayse Just tried Phoenix's code but somehow still applies the same error

Comment: @DevT The screenshots are coming out perfectly, the deletion part is where the error lays, I've posted the screenshot code to see if there was something wrong with it but im guessing it has something to do with file deletion, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to call bmpScreenshot.Close() after bmpScreenshot.Save().

Sorry I was on phone and couldn't check if it had close.

Try this:

```
//Create a new bitmap.
using(var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{

// Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

// Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                            0,
                            0,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

// Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
//bmpScreenshot.Save(nomeScreen + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmpScreenshot.Save(@"c:\temp\"+nomeScreen+".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
count++;
nomeScreen = "S"+Convert.ToString(count);
```

---

So I tested the code and I got some interesting results.

I have this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nomeScreen = "screenshot"+new Random().Next();
        screenshotPath = Application.StartupPath+"\\" + nomeScreen + ".jpeg";
        //Create a new bitmap.
        /*using (*/
        var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);//)
       // {

            // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
        /*using (*/
        var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);//)
            //{

                // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
                gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            //}

            // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
            //bmpScreenshot.Save(nomeScreen + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            bmpScreenshot.Save(screenshotPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       // }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.Delete(screenshotPath);
    }
```

It works fine without any using statements, though in my opinion it is good to have both of the commented out ones. Maybe your problem lies elsewhere. Have you checked your folder's permissions. Maybe you could try saving to the path of the exe of the application? That might fix it. If it does, then you need to check the folder permissions for your "temp" folder or wherever you are trying to save.

Comment: Does not own a .Close method :x

Comment: Still gives me the exact same error, I also just tested to commenting the create a new bitmap area and it gives the same error, any thoughts? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: I will be able to think about it and test it out in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

you can dispose() the Bitmap.....

```
bmpScreenshot.Dispose();
```

Comment: this is what the using statement does... and is better practice to use the using statements in general wherever possible.

Comment: I don't see in the OP a using statement!

Comment: right, I was referring to it as a statement but also the previous answer.